# Webkit WASM stacktrace debugging

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Currently when a webassembly runtime error occurs the stacktrace looks as follows (I'm trying to run Csound as webassembly)

```
"RuntimeError: integer result unrepresentable
at  (<WASM>[5336]+20)
at  (<WASM>[1557]+246)
at  (<WASM>[408]+1475)
at  (<WASM>[6101]+14)
at Object.Module.dynCall_ii (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:9614:89)
at invoke_ii (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:8882:32)
at  (<WASM>[424]+732)
at  (<WASM>[278]+45)
at Module._CsoundObj_performKsmps (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:9606:128)
at ScriptProcessorNode.audioProcessNode.onaudioprocess (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/CsoundObj.js:272:19)"
```

What does (<WASM>[*number1*]+*number2*) mean, especially those numbers?

Answer (score 4):

After some research I discovered that the format is

```
(<WASM>[function_index]+offset)
```

To find the corresponding name of the function index you can use binaryen's `wasm-as` `-s` option which generates an index of functions

```
wasm-as libcsound.wast -s libcsound.sym -o libcsound.wasm
```

This is the contents of libcsound.sym

```
0:Math_pow
1:enlargeMemory
2:getTotalMemory
3:abortOnCannotGrowMemory
...
```

Using libcsound.sym we can enhance the example with WASM function names

```
RuntimeError: integer result unrepresentable
    at  (<WASM>[5336]+20) _lrintf
    at  (<WASM>[1557]+246) _osckk
    at  (<WASM>[408]+1475) _kperf_nodebug
    at  (<WASM>[6101]+14) dynCall_ii
    at Object.Module.dynCall_ii (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:9614:89)
    at invoke_ii (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:8882:32)
    at  (<WASM>[424]+732) _csoundPerformKsmps
    at  (<WASM>[278]+45) jsCall_vi
    at Module._CsoundObj_performKsmps (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:9606:128)
    at ScriptProcessorNode.audioProcessNode.onaudioprocess (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/CsoundObj.js:272:19)
```

The interesting part is the last C function call to [lrintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/lrint/). This function can cause the "integer result unrepresentable" trap when the float to be converted lies outside the long integer range. I edited the C code to check for boundaries first before calling lrint which fixes the problem.

**Update**

When using `-g4` and using Google Chrome Version 60.0.3103.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) function names appear in the stack trace:

```
Uncaught RuntimeError: integer result unrepresentable
    at _lrintf (<WASM>[4176]+6)
    at _osckk (<WASM>[1291]+138)
    at _kperf_nodebug (<WASM>[257]+768)
    at dynCall_ii (<WASM>[4351]+13)
    at Object.Module.dynCall_ii (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:9153:89)
    at invoke_ii (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:8714:32)
    at _csoundPerformKsmps (<WASM>[271]+558)
    at _CsoundObj_performKsmps (<WASM>[131]+33)
    at Module._CsoundObj_performKsmps (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/libcsound.js:9145:128)
    at ScriptProcessorNode.audioProcessNode.onaudioprocess (http://192.168.2.39/~manson/emscripten/csound/emscripten/examples/javascripts/CsoundObj.js:269:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first number is the function index from the WebAssembly [`Code` section](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#code-section). The second is the offset in that function, in bytes, where the trap is being generated (some instructions in WebAssembly generate traps, which turn into JavaScript exceptions). To map the function numbers back you can use tooling such as that provided by [wabt](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) (prebuilt versions are available from [wasm-stat.us](https://wasm-stat.us), see the "archive binaries" step which generates URLs such as `https://storage.googleapis.com/wasm-llvm/builds/mac/5128/wasm-binaries-5128.tbz2`).

You could also use emscripten in debug mode to generate a [`Name` section](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#name-section). Each function index will then map to a name, which will be displayed in the backtrace.

You would use a command-line such as:

```
em++ ./awesome.cc -O2 -g4 -s WASM=1 -o awesome.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['amazing']"
```

`-g4` is the part that adds the `name` section. Don't ship code with this!

On Mac, if you update to a newer [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) you'll get entries such as `"wasm function: 4@[wasm code]`, or if you have debugging enabled something like `wasm function: _spam@[wasm code]` where `spam` was a C function's name. This change is [quite recent](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171263) and will require STP 30 or more recent. Other browsers do similar things. In all cases they also require a fairly recent toolchain because the format of the `name` section has changed.

---

The error you're getting is because a `float` to `int` conversion has a floating-point value which cannot be accurately represented. This traps in WebAssembly, as opposed to producing an unspecified value in most other implementations of C++.

Recently there have been a few bugs in the LLVM implementation of WebAssembly and (I think?) binaryen where some operations which are usually OK to speculate on were hoisted past checks. The bug may very well have been in the code you're running, but there's a slight chance the toolchain unconditionalized that conversion causing the code to trap. Updating the toolchain might remove the bug.

Comment: we answered the question about the same time;)

Comment: Indeed! You found a different solution which is also quite good, I'll totally upvote you :D  I think you want to update to a recent STP and use `-g4`, it'll make things simpler.

Comment: When using `-g4` and using Google Chrome Version 60.0.3103.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) function names appear int the stack trace, see update below

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the "integer result unrepresentable" problem is to use this option:

```
-s "BINARYEN_TRAP_MODE='clamp'"
```

or possibly

```
-s "BINARYEN_TRAP_MODE='js'"
```

see https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly#trap-mode